# How to create a view which supports all screen sizes?

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, size-classes

Hello everyone who reads it. I am trying to make an app looks simillar like Viber or any other app with dial pad to call somebody. But I don't understand how to make a proper design to look app looks equal on every iPhone. I am trying to achieve something like this:

[image: Viber Dial Pad looks perfect on all iPhones]

So I want to get whole keypad looks normal on all iPhones. I already know that I need to add all images for buttons in 3 resolutions, so for 1x I have used 54x54, 2x - 145x145, 3x - 240x240. I have drawn 3 screens in 320x480 (1x), 750x1334 (2x) and 1242x2208 (3x). So on paper everething looks good. But in program, on iPhone 5s, I am facing this:

[image]

If I am trying to decrease sise of 2x images to 124x124 (whole screen will be 640x1136, real iPhone 5s resolution) everething looks good on iPhone 5s, but on iphone 6 (6s also) buttons looks too smal.
So I am trying to understand what should I do to make a real crossIOS application. Any help will be appriciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible in 3 ways :

1. using storyboard with auto layout
   Refrence Url : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/

2.Using xib file with auto layout

3 Make Custom View with Screen Hight and width ratio

Comment: Thank you for reply, but I doubt that second item and third are good. I want to make it right with understanding of AutoLayout....

Answer (score 0):

You have to use proportional height to achieve this

For that:

- Set equal height constraint between screen and any button
- Set aspect ratio 1:1 for all buttons
- Set multiplier according to the requirement of button size
- Set equal height constraint between all buttons

Now you are good to go.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I don't understand first two steps of your list. Please, can you explain it more detail?

Comment: do you use autolayout?

Comment: I am using a constraints but size class is Any Any

Comment: so not an issue set proportional height for button

Comment: I don't understand how to do this: set multiplier as per the requirement of button size

Comment: do you know multiplier?

Comment: Yes, I think I know, it is a number we are using to show, for example percent of the screen, right?

Comment: yes so that you can set proportional height of button and then when you open it in iPhone 6 it will adjust

Comment: And how to do this? Please, I think, this is all I need to know to achieve this...

Comment: or you can follow the steps I provided in answer

Comment: I am not working with code, I am working in Interface Builder in main.storyboard. I need just to understand, how to make step 3. You said a proportion... Which proportion?

Comment: share your storyboard then

Comment: It is long process to write as you are unaware

Comment: How to share this file?

Comment: Ok,  but goole drive!

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B__mf-jCjIFZQXRMTXp4dEgwd28/view?usp=sharing    there is call view

Comment: give me write permission to that file

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B__mf-jCjIFZQXRMTXp4dEgwd28/view?usp=sharing try again, anyone has a permissions to edit

Comment: try this

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8goQl3Zv8dlc0ZIZ1ZQMEo0cjA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: set contentMode to aspectFit for that image of buttons via code

Comment: Ok, but they are compressed only in 5s model. iPhone 6 is good.

Comment: buddy try to improve from you want to achieve

Comment: Yes, I will try... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

put all the buttons in each UIView, use auto layout to set constraints with respect to the UIView(dont constraint the height or width of button), Now use horizontal UIStackView, set distribution to 'fill equally' to fill one row. and one vertical UIStackView, set distribution to 'fill equally' to fill vertically with rows.